# Pagespeed Insights asking to defer images, despite images being deferred

Tags: pagespeed, lighthouse

On my page here:

https://www.wikijob.co.uk/content/aptitude-tests/test-types/aptitude-tests

Using mobile pagespeed insights, I get a 'Defer offscreen images' suggestion on **mobile only**:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikijob.co.uk%2Fcontent%2Faptitude-tests%2Ftest-types%2Faptitude-tests&tab=mobile

[image]

All images on the page are loaded with `loading="lazy"` or `loading="eager"`.

According the source code in Lighthouse, if an image has a lazy/eager tag, it should be passed automatically:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/d0d2ca04c80af8f0443f63072415e34d79a205cc/lighthouse-core/audits/byte-efficiency/offscreen-images.js#L85

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Open the "network" tab in developer tools and look at the "initiator" column, something in your scripts is switching the `src` on the images and this may be negating `loading="lazy"`.

Comment: Looks like you solved this already. Great work on the site, it's blazing fast on all devices.